# Помощь в проектировании таблиц в базе данных

Tags: java, база-данных, spring-security

возник вопрос в проектировании отдельной части базе данных, в частности при использовании Spring Security(Java) у меня будет две роил USER и ADMIN. Соответсвенно и вопрос заключается в следующем как лучше это спроектировать. Стоит ли делать разные таблицы для пользователей и для администраторов? Либо стоит добаить логическое поле у таблицы пользователей is_admin? Хотелось бы получить внятный ответ по поводу этого, не только затрагивая Spring Security, но и в целом как это лучше всего реализовать. Заранее спасибо...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конкретно насчёт Spring Security смотрите [тут](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/appendix-schema.html).

Делать отдельные таблицы на различные роли не стоит.

Как правило делается таблица пользователей (скажем, `TBL_USER`), таблица ролей (`TBL_ROLE`) и связывающая их таблица (`TBL_USER_ROLE`). Иногда добавляют группы.

Comment: можете мне подсказать еще по Spring-у - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/832360/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-google-drive ?

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужна связь `один-ко-многим` 2 таблиц `Users` и `Roles`. В первой будут храниться собственно юзеры. Во второй будут записи `userId` и `userRole`. Так у вас могут получиться юзеры с разным набором ролей. Собственно роли также можно хранить в отдельной таблице и вместо `userRole` записывать `roleId`. Это гибкая и удобная реализация, она используется, в частности в `Spring security`, ибо для интерфейса `UserDetails` требуется реализовать метод получения `authorities` юзера, коий и есть суть его роли.