# Как правильно реализовать функциональность "Поделиться" на подобии как в Google Drive?

Tags: веб-программирование, spring, usercontrol, права, acl

Проектирую сайт, в котором каждый зарегистрированный пользователь, может создавать записи к примеру как в evernote или в том же google диске.

Всего на сайте есть 4 роли *(Админ, Модератор, Поддержка, Пользователь)*, модель для реализации выбрал RBAC и каждой роли назначены нужные права.

---

Но вот не знаю существует ли модель или реализация для Spring для внедрения следующего функционала:

Каждый пользователь может создавать свои группы в которые может добавлять пользователей (Друзья, Коллеги по работе, Семья, и т.д.) добавлять может только тех пользователей которые зарегистрированы на сайте.
Примерно так это вижу в БД:

```html
+------------+---------+--------------+
|   users    | groups  | users_groups |
+------------+---------+--------------+
| id         | id      | id           |
| username   | user_id | group_id     |
| passwords  | name    | user_id      |
+------------+---------+--------------+
```

**Теперь о главной задаче**
Выдавать права доступа к своей записи другим пользователям:

- Доступ по URL (доступен тем у кого есть ссылка)
- Публичный доступ (Доступен всем, также виден в поиске)
- Публичний с паролем
- Группе пользователей
- Конкретному зарегистрированному пользователю

Также к каждому шарингу (доступу) будь то пользователю или группе нужно еще выставлять права:

- Только просмотр
- Просмотр и редактирование
- Полный ( READ / WRITE / DELETE )

[image: Права доступа к документу Spring Boot]

Ну и нужно учесть еще такой пункт, *к примеру у меня есть записи по работе, создал группу "Работа" и добавил в нее сотрудников, и **группе выдал права на просмотр данной записи***, как быть если я добавляю еще один **полный доступ конкретному человеку, но он также есть в группе для чтения** ?

Заранее благодарен за любую помощь или подсказку реализации!

Answer (score 2):

У вас есть таблица записей `items`. Добавьте в нее поле `access_mode` и заполняйте такими значениями

- `NULL`: Только указанные люди

1. Доступ по URL
2. Публичный доступ
3. Публичный с паролем

И заведите таблицу список доступа `acl` с полями

- `id`
- `item_id`
- `group_id`
- `is_read`
- `is_write`
- `is_delete`

Для добавления конкретного пользователя можно для него создать виртуальную группу или добавить в таблицу `acl` поле `user_id` и заполнять или его или поле `group_id` (по идее с виртуальными группами будет проще реализация)

Т.к. у вас есть только разрешительные права и нет запрещающих, то для вычисления конечных прав пользователя на запись достаточно такого запроса

```
SELECT
  MAX(is_read),
  MAX(is_write),
  MAX(is_delete)
FROM
  acl
WHERE
  item_id = :item_id AND
  EXISTS (
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      users_groups ug
    WHERE
      ug.user_id = :user_id AND
      ug.group_id = acl.group_id
  )
```

Comment: Если в таблице items добавить поле access_mode, тогда я смогу давать права только либо группе либо паблик, было бы хорошо найти универсальное решение, чтобы можно было дать доступ группе, одному человеку и по URL тем кого нету на сайте только для просмотра

Comment: @Андрей Т.е. возможна любая комбинация значений? Ну так сделайте тогда битовую маску